# Can I make built-in functions return additional properties?

Tags: javascript

Can I make built-in functions return additional properties?

For example if I call querySelectorAll, can I somehow make the return value contain a desired property (the last element) ?

Instead of:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('span');
var last = elements[elements.length - 1];
```

I want to do:

```
document.querySelectorAll('span').lastElement
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, though I wouldn't recommend it - mutating built-in objects is prone to cause problems.

`querySelectorAll` returns a NodeList, so you can change `NodeList.prototype`.

```js
Object.defineProperty(
  NodeList.prototype,
  'lastElement',
  { get: function() {
    return this[this.length - 1];
  }}
);

console.log(document.querySelectorAll('span').lastElement.textContent);
```

```html
<span>1</span>
<span>2</span>
```

A better approach would be to create and use your own function that has the property added to the returned object.

```js
const mySelectorAll = (selector) => {
  const list = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  return Object.assign(list, { lastElement: list[list.length - 1] });
};

console.log(mySelectorAll('span').lastElement.textContent);
```

```html
<span>1</span>
<span>2</span>
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll go with the second "better" approach. Is it more prone to errors if I don't use object.assign? E.g.: function myfunc(selector)
{   
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    elements.lastElement = elements[elements.length - 1];
    return elements;
}

Comment: @amani the 1st approach is a more direct answer to your question.